# Can't get grunt-contrib-watch to livereload the Browser

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, livereload

Can't get grunt-contrib-watch to livereload the Browser. I've tried to set the default port: 35729 as well but with no luck.

Heres the my Gruntfile:
https://gist.github.com/lukashillebrand/c59d00db555691910da970a5b8a88684

Comment: I'm not sure that "Can't get grunt-contrib-watch" means. Can you check [http://localhost:35729/livereload.js](http://localhost:35729/livereload.js) is there?

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. I´ve switched to gulp now since its faster.